# Laravel add PicoFeed class for laravel

Tags: laravel

i'm installing `PicoFeed` from composer with this configuration on composer.json

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "fguillot/picoFeed",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
          "url": "https://github.com/fguillot/picoFeed",
          "type": "git",
          "reference": "origin/master"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "fguillot/picoFeed": "dev-master"
  },
```

now i think i must be define this class into `app.php` such as `providers` and `aliases` after set this line

```
'Reader'          =>'fguillot\picoFeed\picofeed',
```

in `aliases` and try to use :

```
Route::get('/feed', array('as' => 'feed', function () {
    try {
        $reader = new Reader;
        $resource = $reader->download('http://linuxfr.org/news.atom');
        $parser = $reader->getParser(
            $resource->getUrl()
        );
        $feed = $parser->execute();
        echo $feed;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}));
```

i get this error:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Class 'fguillot\picoFeed\picofeed' not found' in /var/www/livedata/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php:64
```

how to add this class to `providers` on `app.php` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the right class

```
'Reader' => 'PicoFeed\Reader\Reader';
```

Or

```
'Reader' => PicoFeed\Reader\Reader::class;
```

try this. If you have a IDE like phpstorm you will see warning if its not there.